# TCP capture show different user when attempting SMB connection

Tags: windows, network-share, server-message-block, credentials

I'm attempting to map a SMB share on an Isilon server in windows 10.  I have Ubuntu and Windows computers on the same network, can mount the SMB fine on the Ubuntu machine.  But when trying windows with same credentials I get permission denied.  When I do a capture in Wireshark my Windows client can connect to the SMB server and negotiate SMB version etc, but fails:

> 1141  7.886694    clientIP    serverIP    SMB2    636 Session
> Setup Request, NTLMSSP_AUTH, User: ClientMachineName\ClientCurrentUser
>
> 1142  7.888936    serverIP    clientIP    SMB2    151 Session
> Setup Response, Error: STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE

Trouble is I'm supplying a different credentials to SMB, tried using Windows Explorer UI and Powershell, but ClientMachineName\ClientCurrentUser is still sent.  I've tried rebooting the client and also running net use * /delete to no effect.

What causes Windows to send the current user instead of supplied user to SMB?
OR
How can I fix this?

Comment: `I'm supplying a different credentials` How?

Comment: In Windows explorer I try mapping a network drive, then check the "Connect using different credentials" box, Windows then prompts for a username and password.  powershell using the New-PSDrive command and supplying creds using System.Management.Automation.PSCredential object

Comment: Explorer does not work that way, although there may be a setting to adjust.  https://superuser.com/a/1417657/31845

Comment: @GregAskew it totally does, I have other SMB shares mapped this way on the same Windows computer.

Comment: @Geordie Windows can only ever use a single logon session for each user to a specific SMB server. If you need multiple logon sessions to a certain server then you need multiple users.

Comment: @Geordie: the link on SuperUser explains the threading issues and a registry modification workaround  hack. It isn't a topic for this forum as it usually isn't needed, and the issue does not occur in more likely use cases, such as from a command prompt when performing automated tasks.